# Norm of $L^2$ functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the functional $T: L^2((0,1)) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
T(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) (1-x) dx.
$$
Calculate $\lVert T \rVert$.

---

I can show that
$$
|T(f)| \leq \int_0^1 |f(x) (1-x)| dx \leq \left( \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx \right)^{1/2}  
\left( \int_0^1 (1-x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2}= \lVert f \rVert_2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}
$$
using Hölder inequality. Which means $\lVert T \rVert \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Now I need to find $f \in L^2(0,1)$, $\lVert f \rVert \leq 1$ (or a sequence) such that
$\lVert T(f) \rVert = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know when equality holds in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Iff $f$ and $1-x$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Well, then try some $f$ that is linearly dependent on $1-x$.

Comment: $\sqrt{3} (1-x)$ will work. Thank you.

Comment: @MaoWao feel free to write the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both inequalities in the question we have inequality if $f(x)=\alpha(1-x)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, if $\alpha=\pm\sqrt{3}$, then $\|f\|_2=1$ and $\|Tf\|_2=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$.